# Regex for extracting all heading digits from a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract all heading digits from a string using Java regex without writing additional code and I could not find something to work:

`"12345XYZ6789ABC"` should give me `"12345"`.
`"X12345XYZ6789ABC"` should give me nothing

```
public final class NumberExtractor {
    private static final Pattern DIGITS = Pattern.compile("what should be my regex here?");

    public static Optional<Long> headNumber(String token) {
        var matcher = DIGITS.matcher(token);
        return matcher.find() ? Optional.of(Long.valueOf(matcher.group())) : Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if the upvote giver would provide a short explanation for the unvote reason. Thanks, no offence but I think this is a fair expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *word boundary* `\b`:

```
\b\d+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Km7A0rY0EyOG2N).

If you strictly want to match only digits at the start of the input, and not from each word (same thing when the input contains only one word), use `^`:

```
^\d+
```

---

```
Pattern DIGITS = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+"); // leading digits of all words
Pattern DIGITS = Pattern.compile("^\\d+"); // leading digits of input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think something like "^[0-9]*" would work. There's a \d that matches other Unicode digits if you want to include them as well.

Edit: removed errant . from the string.

Comment: I tried testing `\d` against the Arabic digits.  It didn't match.  I didn't try digits from other languages, but I'm fairly sure that `\d` only matches `[0-9]`, and not any other Unicode digits.  Also, that `.` really doesn't belong there.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Try `(?U)\d` to match digits from non-English scripts/languages.

Comment: Great tip, thanks @Shawn